# How to restrict props.children in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Message from "./components/Message";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Message>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </Message>
            <Message>
                <a>Hello World</a>
            </Message>
            <Message>
                <button>Hello World</button>
            </Message>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';

interface OwnProps {
    children: React.ReactElement<HTMLParagraphElement>;
}

type Props = OwnProps;

const Message: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({children}) => {

    return (
        <h1>
            {children}
        </h1>
    );
};

export default Message;
```

The above code I can pass any HTMLElementTag as props. 
Is there any way to restrict ReactElement to only specific element ?
For example only with p tag or button tag etc.

Comment: It is impossible to do without workarounds. See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-jsx-result-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render specific children with `React.Children` by checking its type.
Below example only renders p tag elements.

```
import React, { Children } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactElement<HTMLParagraphElement | HTMLHeadElement>[] | React.ReactElement<HTMLParagraphElement | HTMLHeadElement>;
}

const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const elements = Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if ((child as React.ReactElement).type === "p") {
      return child;
    }
    return null;
    
  })?.filter(Boolean);

  return <div>{elements}</div>;
};

export default Component;
```

Note that type of custom component is a function, not string.
And if you want to check types of nested html elements, you need to recursively check types of react elements children.

I do not know what you are trying to do here, but there may be a better approach than restricting render of children elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the wrong way to be going about implementing HTMl here: if you want a `<h1>` element to render then you shouldn't be passing `<p>` or `<button>` elements into it.

Why not just leave the functional component input here as just a string? Like so:

```
import React from 'react';

interface MessageProps {
    messageText: string;
}

const Message: React.FC<MessageProps> = ({ messageText }) => {

    return (
        <h1>
            {messageText}
        </h1>
    );
};

export default Message;

//////


import React from 'react';
import Message from "./components/Message";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Message messageText="Hello world" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use following for static checking:

```
type Props = { children: React.ReactNode } //-- allow any React valid Node
// type Props = { children: never } //-- will not allow children to be passed
```